# Equipment for starting with SLA printing

Tags: sla, uv-printer, anycubic-photon

I am completely new to 3D printing and want to start with SLA printing.
I found the Anycubic Photon Mono 2 printer, but on the [ordering page](https://www.anycubic.com/products/photon-mono-x2-sla-3d-printer), there are options for "Airpure" and "Wash & Cure" machines.

I do not know what these are, nor if they are needed for SLA printing.
Can someone explain the function of these items, and if they are needed for SLA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Airpure](https://www.anycubic.com/products/anycubic-airpure) is an air filtration device for use **inside** the SLA printer to scrub the air for fumes.

The [Wash & Cure](https://www.anycubic.com/collections/wash-cure-machine) machines are to rinse the resin off of the printed model. Since the resin is UV reactant, the "Cure" part of the device is to solidify the model into a solid form. (Note: This is a two-step process)

While these devices are absolutely necessary (you could come up with other solutions) they are readily-made solutions by the same manufacturer.

I would recommend watching some YouTube videos on SLA or resin printing to understand the use of the Wash & Cure machines.

Comment: Seems like the Wash&Cure could be easily DIYed. I will watch videos on SLA, however, how is the resin cured? UV light?

Comment: Yes, there are several videos about using DIY curing setups. And yes, the resin is cured with UV light.

Comment: Thank you! One last thing. The curing has to happen at a specific time interval? Or you can literally do it the next day or week and the finished part will be fine?

Comment: Because of the chemicals in the resin, it is best to cure it as soon as possible. Not to mention that an uncured model could deform since it has not solidified.

Answer (score 1):

Airpure can be replaced with a good fan and duct that sucks fumes out from the printer and vents them outdoors away from any living creatures. Not practical in many situations, but can be much cheaper if your situation allows.

I've seen a hobbyist making excellent prints where his "Wash & Cure" were a big jar with a lid, filled with isopropanol (to be shaken vigorously with the print inside) and a UV flashlight (to shine at the print from all directions).

What you really shouldn't skimp on is a good quality rebreather and eye protection.

Comment: While the information you present is not wrong, it doesn't directly answer the question of what the items are and their function. (Not trying to offend or anger, just giving helpful advice)